# A question regarding forcing in $NGBC^{-f}$+$BAFA$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Suppose one has a model $M$$\vDash$$NGBC^{-f}$+BAFA.  Does there exist a (class) forcing extension $M[G]$$\vDash$$NGBC^{-f}$+$BAFA$ that has a submodel $N$$\vDash$$NGB^{-f}$+$BAFA$+$\lnot$$AC$?  Can one also construct permutation models of $NGB^{-f}$+$BAFA$+$\lnot$$AC$?

Note $NGB^{-f}$ is von Neumann-Goedel-Bernays set theory without the axiom of foundation.

$BAFA$ is Boffa's Anti-Foundation Axiom; that is, that

"...for every transitive set $t_0$ and every extensional binary relation $<$$a$,$e$$>$ that end-extends $<$$t_0$, $\in$$>$, meaning $t_0$$\subseteq$$a$ and $\in$$\upharpoonright$$t_0$=$e$$\cap$($a$$\times$$t_0$), there exists a transitive set $t$, and an isomorphism from $<$$a$,$e$$>$ to $<$$t$,$\in$$>$ that is the identity on $t_0$..."

(this from Daghighi's, Golshani's, Hamkins',and Jerabek's preprint "The Role of the Foundation Axiom in the Kunen Inconsistency", from which the notation was taken and the motivation for this question.)

Comment: Suggested improvement: Give definitions of the theories.

Comment: I think the first thing to do is to properly define "forcing" over models of BAFA! Note that even forcing over models of AFA - a much tamer antifoundation axiom - took real effort: see S. Kentaro's article http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/malq.200410060/abstract. The problem is that without Foundation it's not clear how to define a name or the interpretation of a name.

Comment: Actually, this article might be more directly related: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.1968.pdf. See also http://users.auth.gr/tzouvara/Texfiles.htm/forcing.pdf. (By the way, is there a reason you care about the class-theoretic version instead of the set-theoretic version?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  I care about the class-theoretic version for the same reason that  Hamkins and others say that $NGBC$ can better capture the import of the Kunen inconsistency than can $ZFC$+'$j$'.  If $NGBC$ can better capture the import of the Kunen inconsistency, then perhaps class forcing would be the  better method for constructing models of  $NGB^{-f}$+ $BAFA$+$\lnot$$AC$.  Since I am not at all sure about this, I added  class forcing (in parentheses) for completeness.  In which case, one might want to adjust the definition of $BAFA$ to suit--replace every occurrence of 'set' in that

Comment: (cont.) definition with 'class'.  If this idea is wrong-headed, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Thanks for the links in your comments.  I am especially interested in  arxiv.org/pdf/0712.1968.pdf since it directly (favorably) mentions Boffa.  The problem is, is that  Johnson ends his paper in the middle (so to speak).  Do you know if he has the completion of his forcing method in another paper?  If so, please provide the link to that paper also.

Comment: I don't - this isn't material I'm at all familiar with. I sat down with a student a year ago to try to work out forcing over $ZF^{-f}$ and ran into difficulties, so when I saw this question my interest was piqued, but I don't actually *know* anything here.

Comment: By the way, fun fact, another non-foundational theory which can make sense of forcing is Quine's New Foundations! http://math.boisestate.edu/~holmes/holmes/informal_forcing